# laravel request session from other project

Tags: laravel, session, windows-10

Hello I have a problem.

Laravel Installer 4.2.8
terminal original cmd of window
windows 10

the project its work fine yesterday.

but today it request session from other path than the project is runing.
i search for the other path in all the project but not find anythick

I get this error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK I use `php artisan config:clear` and its work

Comment: it also looks like you may have blindly copy-pasted something that included the old paths in it

Comment: @apokryfos No, I create this project from 1 year, and its the first time it make this error